# php barcode scan manipulate data web form

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, barcode

Thank you for any help in steering me in the right direction. I have a php form that has been running since 2014 inputting data into a mysql database. Now i would like to scan a barcode into one field, but i only need certain data from this barcode scan.  When I scan it i get a long string of data.

example of data i get when i scan the barcode

```
<Bearing>
   <COMPANYcODE>c480</COMPANYcODE>
   <IDnUMBER>l412040193</idNumber>
   <C203>PRBK</C203>
   <C204>2020-05-20T15:33:51</C204>
   <C205>428946</C205>
   <C206>13</C206>
   <C207>11</C207>
   <C208>6.5</C208>
   <C209>9.0</C209>
   <C210>27</C210>
   <C21l>R</C2ll>
   <C213>8AMS00OS</C213>
   <C214>SOEX0003</C214>
   <C215>AARX0002</C215>
   <C216>AARX0001</C216>
   <C217>AARX0001</C217>
</Bearing>
```

On my input field I only want the numbers between the C205 c206 and c207 above all on one line no spaces.

Im not sure how to do this. Basically when i scan the barcode i would like this one input field to only show 4289461311 using the example above.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
I can send my code example if needed. But its just a simple input form. Also if its easier to change the data once it gets added to mysql database, any help on doing that would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I just need the data <C205>428946</C205><C206>13</C206><C207>11</C207>  Basically need to strip everything away but the numbers.  so my input for this above should be 4289461311

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a way to do it:**

```
$data = "<Bearing><COMPANYcODE>c480</COMPANYcODE><IDnUMBER>l412040193</idNumber><C203>PRBK</C203><C204>2020-05-20T15:33:51</C204><C205>428946</C205><C206>13</C206><C207>11</C207><C208>6.5</C208><C209>9.0</C209><C210>27</C210><C21l>R</C2ll><C213>8AMS00OS</C213><C214>SOEX0003</C214><C215>AARX0002</C215><C216>AARX0001</C216><C217>AARX0001</C217></Bearing>";

if(!preg_match_all('/<(C205|C206|C207)>(.+?)<\/\1>/', $data, $out)) {
    echo "No Data Found";
} else {
    $myvalues = join('', $out[2]);
    echo $myvalues;
}

// output:
// 4289461311
```

Comment: Just a note: this will only work if the input is always formatted exactly the same way. If things like spaces might appear around element names or values, or the element names might change case, or anything else could change the formatting in any way, then you should consider using an XML parser that can parse broken XML.

Comment: I will give this a try  Thank you for taking the time to respond and help.